# Adjusting datagrid columns in a C# Windows application

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagrid

How can I adjust the column widths based on a datagrid's displayed values in a C# Windows application?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do this within the designer in Visual Studio.

Comment: i just want to know how?
any examples

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using MeasureString to compute the size of the text in each cell, and then take the maximum value.

You can find the code snippet to do this here - http://www.syncfusion.com/FAQ/windowsforms/faq_c44c.aspx#q877q

Comment: its a sms to PC application so each row is adding to grid one by one.so how can i change the cell width for this?

Comment: you can perhaps have a variable which holds the width of the max cell value for each column. So when each row is added, you can compare the new value with the previous maximum value and set the column width accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using DataGridView as your datagrid control there's an AutoSizeColumns property that if set to true it will adjust columns widths automatically.

Comment: i want to know about datagrid

Comment: this might help http://windowsclient.net/downloads/folders/starterkits/entry1303.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Well one approach is to set the attribute **AutoSizeColumnsMode** to **"Fill"** which will resize the columns dynamically in order to fill the extent of the grid. Then, for each column you can also specify the **FillWeight** (in "*Edit Columns*") in order to have a "*weighted*" resizing of the columns.

Otherwise you can set the default width for each column by setting the "**Width**" attribute in "*Edit Columns*"

If you want to do this programmatically at runtime, you can do it by calling

```
dataGridView1.Columns[...].Width = XX
```

Comment: its a datagrid not datagridviewer

Comment: @kiran: If you're creating this from scratch, I highly recommend the `DataGridView` control. `GridView` is deprecated, and offers less functionality.